# Как установить границы для перемещения картинки

Tags: java, android, xml

Столкнулся с проблемой ,что при перемещении картинки она может покинуть активную часть экрана ,т.е пропасть за пределами layout вот код разметки

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/font"
    tools:context=".cs2.mapgranade.Activity_cs_map_granade">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_back_svg"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            app:tint="@color/white" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вот сам код Activity

```
public class Activity_cs_map_granade extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    private Float scaleFactor = 1.0f;
    private Float x, y, dx, dy;
    private String typeOfGranade;
    private String mapName;
    private ImageView mapImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cs_map_granade);

        ImageView backButton = findViewById(R.id.backButton);

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        typeOfGranade = intent.getStringExtra("typeOfGranade");
        mapName = intent.getStringExtra("mapName").toLowerCase();
        mapImage = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(mapName + "map", "drawable", getPackageName());
        mapImage.setImageResource(imageResource);

        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                dx = event.getX() - x;
                dy = event.getY() - y;
                mapImage.setX(mapImage.getX() + dx);
                mapImage.setY(mapImage.getY() + dy);
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 10.0f));

            // Get the initial width and height of the image
            float initialWidth = mapImage.getWidth();
            float initialHeight = mapImage.getHeight();

            // Calculate the scaled width and height
            float scaledWidth = initialWidth * scaleFactor;
            float scaledHeight = initialHeight * scaleFactor;

            // Check if the scaled dimensions are greater than or equal to the initial dimensions
            if (scaledWidth >= initialWidth && scaledHeight >= initialHeight) {
                mapImage.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
                mapImage.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: так а в чем проблема, берете родителя и проверяете вхождение вашей ImageView.